# How to declare an array of function pointers without using a typedef for the function pointer?

Tags: c

I was demonstrating to a learning colleague how to use function pointers and how he could have an array of them. I put down the following code so that he could do indexed dispatch:

```
typedef void (*VoidFunction)();
VoidFunction functions[]  =
    {editProgramName,
     editProgramLength,
     editProgramCycles,
     editProgramNumberOfSets,
     editProgramEditSets,
     editProgramSave,
     editProgramCancel};
// now dispatch                    
functions[scroll.arrayFocusIndex]();
```

And then he asked... "How do I do it without the typedef?" To which I found after trying various things that seemed like they might work, I didn't have a clue to do. All the google hits I found always seemed to use a typedef. Is there a way to do it inline without the typedef of the function pointer?

Comment: Yes. The syntax would be: `void (*functions[])() = {...`

Comment: @JerryCoffin You're quick. I was going to post that. (May I still do it?)

Comment: Oh, and OP: +1 for a good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void (*functions[])() =
    {editProgramName,
     editProgramLength,
     editProgramCycles,
     editProgramNumberOfSets,
     editProgramEditSets,
     editProgramSave,
     editProgramCancel};
// now dispatch
functions[scroll.arrayFocusIndex]();
```

Comment: Dammit, I started testing this before Jerry Coffin posted his comment. Honest.

Comment: Could have sworn that was one of the darts I threw at it, but apparently not. Seems obvious when I look at it now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

This has worked for me:

```
void a()
{
}

void b()
{
}

void (*functions[2])();

int main()
{
    functions[0] = a;
    functions[1] = b;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @GManNickG Why delete your answer? It was good. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: Your first comment to Jerry was 3 second earlier than my answer. :) So I'm concluding you saw the question first.

Comment: @GManNickG Maybe yes. Who knows :)

Comment: Gave you both an upvote to try and even things out a little. :)

Comment: @H2CO3 - What was your answer?